# Is there a way to execute a script after make returns?

Tags: c++, makefile, gdb, command-line-interface, avr

I'm trying to be more efficient in being lazy... so in order to fire up avarice and gdb after the build I added this to my Makefile:

```
gdb:
    make
    ./start_avarice.sh & \
    avr-gdb target.elf
```

This sort of works, avarice is running in the background and avr-gdb is fired up. 
But I can't see any commands I type into the gdb-cli. It's like the last line of the cli doesn't show:

```
Reading symbols from target.elf...done.
0x00007000 in ?? ()
(gdb) Can't see this line and don't know what I'm typing here! <RETURN>
Undefined command: "Can't see this line and don't know what I'm typing here!".  Try "help".
```

Other than that, avr-gdb seems to be working fine.

```
(gdb) b Bus.cpp:512
Breakpoint 1 at 0x2064: file /home/mrv/sketchbook/libraries/libPam/bus/Bus.cpp, line 512.

(gdb) i b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x00002064 in Bus::updateUUID(unsigned long) at /home/mrv/sketchbook/libraries/libPam/bus/Bus.cpp:512

(gdb) c
Continuing.
```

Obviously make is still running while I'm in gdb. Could this be the reason for the weird display of the cli?

Is there a way to execute a script/command after make returns?

```
gdb:
    make
    <when_make_returns_do> 
        ./start_avarice.sh & \
        avr-gdb target.elf
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you running make from inside make? Did you just want to give the `gdb` target a prerequisite on your default target so make handles that for you? Do you need to run `start_avarice.sh` and `avr-gdb` in the same shell session or can they be in different sessions? Does something need to *stop* avarice at some point? Does running `avr-gdb` from make (in a simpler `gdb-test: ; avr-gdb target.elf` target) work correctly or have this problem also? Running under `make` is certainly a different environment than running directly under the shell (`make` may be buffering output, etc.).

Comment: I want to be able to simply run "make gdb" and make is supposed to build (hence the make in the make), start avarice and avr-gdb.

Avarice and avr-gdb don't need to run in the same session. Avarice starts a server on localhost on a specified port that avr-gdb can connect to. Avarice needs to be running all the time, no need to stop the process. 

Yes, starting avarice "manually" and avr-gdb through make gives the same error.

| "make may be buffering output"
I'm afraid so. :(

Comment: If they don't need the same session then you don't need the `& \` bit there and can just use two lines. You may also want to use an independent target for the server (if there's a file you can check for to see if it is already started especially). What version of `make` is this?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to run these scripts from *within* Make? What's wrong with `make gdb; ./start_avarice.sh &; avr-gdb target.elf`? If that's too much finger-work, you can create an alias for it.

Comment: @Beta I have around 10 different targets (flash bootloader, flash via spi, jtag, usb, tftp, flash eeprom, gimme assembly, show me avr-size, debugger, etc...)  I just want everything to be consistent.

Comment: @EtanReisner running GNU make 3.8.1. Thanks for the suggestions. I'm on the road today. Will test Monday when I'm back at the office ;)

Comment: None of my (unfortunately badly formatted) previous comment will change the issue at hand (just clean up the makefile a bit). That said I don't think 3.81 does buffering (the way 4.0+ can) so that's not likely the issue. `avr-gdb` may be detecting the environment incorrectly though. You might want to try playing with `bash -i -c 'avr-gdb ...'` or similar to see if you can fix that (but without knowing *why* `avr-gdb` is working the way it is I'm not sure what else to suggest.